# Use VertexTool in QGIS/PyQGIS standalone application

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, standalone

I want to have a simple possibility to edit the geometry of a polygon in a QGIS standalone application. The VertexTool from QGIS would work well.

I am in a standalone application and have therefore no `iface` to use the `actionVertexTool` action.

I found out, that there should exist a 'QgsVertexTool' class, but I cannot find this one in the docs (https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/search.html?q=QgsVertexTool&check_keywords=yes&area=default).

I thought, that I could set the `MapTool` with the `QgsVertexTool`, like I do it e.g. for the 'pan' action:

```
self.panTool = QgsMapToolPan(self.canvas)
self.canvas.setMapTool(self.panTool)
```

How can I use the VertexTool in a QGIS standalone application?
Is there another simple possibility to edit the geometry of a polygon in a standalone QGIS canvas?